# Initializing an array of strings in Rust

Tags: arrays, rust

I want to create a mutable array of a fixed size. The elements are initialized later in the program. How do I initialize the array?

I tried doing this:

```
let mut array: [String; 126] = [String::new(); 126];
```

and it gives me the error:

```
the trait bound 'std::string::String: std::marker::Copy' is not satisfied
the trait 'std::marker::Copy' is not implemented for 'std::string::String'
```

how do I initialize the array with new strings?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

At the moment, initialization of arrays is still a bit quirky.
In particular, having `Default` would have been useful here, but it's only implemented for arrays up to 32:

```
let array: [String; 32] = Default::default();
```

Any number over that will fail to compile because, while Rust 1.47 now implements some traits over a generic size for array types, `Default` is yet not one of them. These 32 implementations of `Default` were "sort-of" added manually.

We can overcome that with alternative container types, such as `Vec`. The `vec!` macro will let you clone a string as many times as you wish to fill in the new vector:

```
let mut array: Vec<String> = vec![String::new(); 126];
```

But of course, depending on your use case, you might also consider going lazy and only collecting the final outcomes using the [Iterator API](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/index.html).

Comment: wow, so what if we wanted to initialize an array of strings in rust of just red, blue, green, what would that look like?

Comment: @Daniel that would be a different question, but see the relevant book section. https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch08-01-vectors.html#creating-a-new-vector

Answer (score 6):

There are ways that work for types without `const` ways to construct them, for example:

```
let mut a = [(); 126].map(|_| String::new());
```

The other answer with `const EMPTY_STRING: String = String::new()` is probably better for this particular case, as the documentation of the [`array::map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html#method.map) method warns that this might be inefficient and consume a lot of stack space.

In nightly (as of Rust 1.57), there is also an even nicer function [`std::array::from_fn()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/array/fn.from_fn.html).

Answer (score 4):

You can use (the result of) a [const function](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/const_eval.html#const-functions), for example [`String::new()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.new), to initialize an array:

```rust
const EMPTY_STRING: String = String::new();
let mut array: [String; 126] = [EMPTY_STRING; 126];
```